# Is it possible to run both FTP proxy server and FTP server on the same machine on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, proxy, ftp, network-programming

Anybody know whether it is possible to run FTP proxy server and FTP server on the same machine with Windows OS? If yes then second question appears. How is it possible that proxy will catch FTP traffic before FTP server will catch this, seeing as how both will listen on the same ports, because as I understand FTP listen on ports 21 and 20?

I'm asking this question because I have to implement my own FTP proxy server to restrict some FTP command or to forbid viewing files with some extensions. Right now for me every answer is very helpful, because I don't have a lot of knowledge about this. If someone is able point me to good source of knowledge about this topic how to implement own FTP proxy server it would be great.

Anybody knows if it is possible to implement FTP proxy server with above functionality using C#. If no what is the best programming language to do so?

Comment: A lot of FTP servers will allow you to configure file types to restrict and what functionality to allow without the need to write your own proxy.

Comment: Run the proxy on ports 20/21 and configure the real server to use a different port.  then your proxy will, erm, proxy data between the proxy and the real server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your proxy on the standard FTP port (21). Run the real FTP server on a non-standard port. Only the proxy needs to know the non-standard port. You will also not want the FTP server port to be accessible from the outside.

Though as @Diado commented already, many servers will allow you to configure allowed FTP commands on their own.